# PHP Captcha - Session from generated image ist not stored

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a form that generated a captcha, which of course will be checked afterwards. This also worked great in my test environment.

Now i have integrated the form in a onlineshop and it doesn't work. The image for the captcha is generated. But apparently the security code whoich is generated in captcha.ph is not saved in the SESSION.

This is the code I use to insert the image:

```
<?
session_start();
?>
<img src="/media/content/captcha.php?RELOAD=" alt="Captcha" title="Klicken, um das Captcha neu zu laden" onclick="this.src+=1;document.getElementById('captcha_code').value='';" width="130px" height="38px" />
<input type="text" name="captcha_code" id="captcha_code" class="form-control"/>

<?
echo 'Test: '.$_SESSION['captcha_spam'].'';
?>
```

This is the Code from the capcha.php

```
<?
#Ersetellt eine Session, wenn dies noch nicht passiert ist.
session_start();
#Setzt das bestehende Captcha zurück.
unset($_SESSION['captcha_spam']);

#Allgemeine Variablen für das Captcha-Bild
$captcha_bg_img     = 'https://akkurato.de/media/content/etl-formular/bg_captcha.png';          #Pfad zum Hintergrundbild
$captcha_over_img   = 'https://akkurato.de/media/content/etl-formular/bg_captcha_over.png'; #Pfad zum Bild, was über das Captcha gelegt wird
$font_file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/public/fonts/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc9.ttf';
#$font_file             = 'https://akkurato.de/public/fonts/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc9.ttf';
#$font_file             = dirname(__FILE__).'/railway-webfont.ttf'; #Pfad zur Schriftdatei
$font_size          = 25;                                       #Schriftgröße
$text_angle         = mt_rand(0, 5);                            #Schriftwinkel (Werte zwischen 0 und 5)
$text_x             = mt_rand(0, 18);                           #X-Position (Werte zwischen 0 und 18)
$text_y             = 35;                                       #Y-Position
$text_chars         = 5;                                        #Länge des Textes
$text_color         = array(0, 0 , 0);                          #Textfarbe (R, G, B)
    
#Generiert einen zufälligen String.
#Verwendet keine 0, 1, I, O da sich diese ähnlich sehen.
function rand_string($length=5) {
    $letters = array_merge(range('A', 'H'), range('J', 'N'), range('P', 'Z'), range(2, 9));
    $lettersCount = count($letters) - 1;        
    $result = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $result .= $letters[mt_rand(0, $lettersCount)];
        }
    return $result;
}

#Generiert einen zufälligen Text.
$text = rand_string($text_chars);
$_SESSION['captcha_spam'] = $text;
    
#Header: Mitteilen, dass es sich um ein Bild handelt und dass dieses nicht im Cache gespeichert werden soll.
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT');
header("Last-Modified: ".date("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-type: image/png');
    
#Captcha Bild erstellen, Text schreiben & Bild darüber legen.
$img = ImageCreateFromPNG($captcha_bg_img);
$text_color = ImageColorAllocate($img, $text_color[0], $text_color[1], $text_color[2]);
imagettftext($img, $font_size, $text_angle, $text_x, $text_y, $text_color, $font_file, $text);
imagecopy($img, ImageCreateFromPNG($captcha_over_img), 0, 0, 0, 0, 140, 40);
    
#Ausgabe und Löschen des Bildes.
imagepng($img); 
imagedestroy($img); 
?>
```

Both files are in the same directory.

What can be the reason that I can't print the content of the session? All other sessions where print. This Code worked without any problems on my test system. It is now integrated into a shop system (not as an iFrame!), could it be due to a cache system or something?

I had inserted the file with and without the URL (https:://), but there was no difference either.

I used the search function and couldn't find any solution.

Comment: _"This is the code I use to insert the image:"_ - so that most likely means, other output was sent to the client before already; in which case you can't use any functions that try to set an HTTP response header any more - but that is what session_start will do, it'll try to add a `Set-Cookie` header for the session cookie. If this works for you on your test system, then you most likely had output buffering enabled there by default. (Which will mitigate the header issue, but is not the recommended way to handle such a situation.)

Comment: Are those base images you are using there stored on a different server? If not, then you should really rather work with file system paths instead of HTTP URLs. Having to make an HTTP request every time, is a much more "costly" operation, than to simply read the file contents via the file system.

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting the capcha.php page by echoing out the result?  There may be a silent error or notice that's preventing the SESSION being written.

It might also be wise to set your PHP session_save_path if you're on shared hosting and move it to outside your webroot, but within your own hosting folder.

Comment: I have change the code and use now the file system paths instead of HTTP URLs.

How can I output the result with echo?

Comment: I had previously tested it without an online shop. I don't want to change the general configuration now either, after that the shop no longer works properly.

Does it make sense to see if I somehow put the PHP code to create the image directly into the form, with a function?

Because the contents of the session variable are saved on the page with the form. I just don't know how to rebuild it to make it work.

I could save the code in a function, but I don't know how to call it again with JS as soon as you click on the image. I'm not familiar with JS.